# Preliminary Orbit Determination Packages

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit-determination

I have been looking for free orbit determination packages that take in 3 sets of RA,DEC and time, along with observation position and spits out a preliminary orbit estimate. Even if it is a Matlab/python package, that I will have to tweak is fine, as long as it gives me orbit estimates from inputted observation data.

Comment: Would [find_orb](https://github.com/Bill-Gray/find_orb) and it's hands-off commandline version `fo` work for you ? Otherwise something like the elderly book ['Methods of Orbit Determination for the Micro Computer'](https://www.willbell.com/math/mc10.htm) but is still valid and has details on the classic Laplace's and Gauss's methods which will take 3 positions/times and make an (preliminary) orbit

Comment: Check the other questions, answers and comments associated with the [`orbit-determination`](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbit-determination) tag. You may find something helpful and be able to answer your own question!